# Add authorize keys for users via chef

Tags: chef-infra, chef-solo

I'm trying to add authorized keys for my deploy using chef but I'm getting a no method error.

#### error

```
[2016-01-25T21:24:01+00:00] ERROR: No resource or method named `user_ssh_keys_key' for `Chef::Recipe "user"'
```

#### user.rb

```
user_ssh_keys_key 'deploy' do
  authorized_keys node['ssh_public_keys']
  authorized_users %w(deploy)
end
```

#### berksfile

```
cookbook 'user-ssh-keys', '~> 1.0.2'
```

#### attributes/default.rb

```
default['ssh_public_keys'] = ['...','...']
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you please check you've added the dependency to the `user-ssh-keys` cookbook in your `metadata.rb` ?

It should look like this:

`depends 'user-ssh-keys', '~> 1.0.2'`

Comment: Now it fails on ```Data Bag Items must contain a Hash or Mash!```

Comment: would you like to share your data bags?